# Can I exit (return) prematurely from a Class constructor?

Tags: php, class

I need to exit *prematurely* from a class constructor if one of the arguments in the constructor satisfy a certain condition, can I just use return as in the example below or there's another way to do that?

```
class Test {

  public function __construct( arg1, arg 2 ) {

    switch case( arg2 ) {
      case 'case1':
        ...do some settings for the code to follow...
      break;
      case 'case2':
        return; // Can I do this?
      break;
    }

    ...Other code to execute if args2 wasn't 'case2'...

  }

}
```

Thanks to everyone who'll answer.

**Edit**

For anyone who could find the question weird: in some languages a constructor should return specific values in order to actually create a class, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: _// Can I do this?_ well... what result do you get when you run a test?

Comment: @jibsteroos Apparently there's nothing wrong with using return as I did in the example,  I mean I didn't get any error (otherwise I would have told). The question is just about if that is an acceptable method to exit or not in a class constructor as I didn't found much info about this.

Comment: Sure it is. Write readable code and it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

`__construct` is just a normal function invoked by a normal function call, and yes, you can `return` from that function at any time as you can with any other function too. Note that whatever *value* you `return` from `__construct` will be ignored, but that's apparently of no concern here.

For that reason (that `__construct` doesn't return anything), I'd refrain from a premature exit *for readability reasons*, but there's no technical reason to. I'd rather prefer an *if-this-do-that* pattern than an *if-this-stop-prematurely* pattern for a constructor.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for. As told in the edit I was just curious about if there's a specific return value to set in a PHP class constructor.